# Is it possible to have over inheritance to be lost in code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I'm currently working on an asp.net site, done by someone else, and it's rediculously over complicated for what it does......Well I think so! Pretty much every class inherits from another class then another and another and so on and on....... You have to go about 8/10 levels on average to get the the base class, sometimes more! And these classes have other classes inside which follow the same pattern of Uber Inheritence.
This leaves me lost in code many many times resulting in God knows how many tabs open on visual studio.

Is this good/normal practice or is it bad practice? I feel it's bad practice as something so simple is made over complicated with an over usage of inheritance resulting in un-extensible code...............but I could be wrong :)

Thanks!

Comment: another architecture astronaut ? (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html)

Comment: Yes, it sounds like pretty lousy code, for whatever comfort it is to hear that. Now, perhaps you want to ask a question about how to refactor it into something a bit less nasty?

Comment: Is the documentation sufficient for all classes? Do they have decent naming and is the 'top' class pretty easy to use?

Comment: in a lot of the GUI frameworks you can get multiple levels of inheritence. Just looking at the hierarchy for WPF, I can see several classes that go 8 levels deep from C# Object.

Comment: @Jimmy: and what do you think this means? (Hint: it does **not** mean that 8 levels of inheritance is good design!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, over-using inheritance can lead to a spaghetti warehouse. Inheritance is a tool to allow for encapsulation and abstraction. Abusing it causes too much abstraction and then the purpose of the code becomes unusable. I've seen this pattern abused in imperative constructs as well where a method is passed from method to method to method before an action is actually applied.

```
private bool getData()
{
    return getOtherData();
}

private bool getOtherData()
{
    return getSomeExtraData();
} 

private bool getSomeExtraData()
{
    return SeeHowTediousThisIs();
}
```

It all works, but it's just an exceptionally bad architecture for maintenance. I find this often occurs with consultants/contractors attempting to introduce complexity (re: job security).

Comment: Yes, definitly sapghetti warehouse and classes are over abstracted to a rediculous degree!

thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 5):

There is a design guideline of 'favour composition over inheritance' 8-10 levels on inheritance breaks that somewhat.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like inheritance-overkill, very rarely should need to go beyond 2-3 levels, and that would be for a complex business model.

What sort of classes are these? Controls? Business Objects?  Are they documented (UML) anywhere so that you can get a good overview of the model?

8-10 levels deep is a lot, I would hazard a guess that these classes were coded before (or never) designed.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance as a means to reusing code is a pretty bad choice indeed. Consider that every class in .NET-based languages have a **single** slot of inheritance where code can go. Hence, for each class it should be chosen wisely whether it should inherit from something else or not.

Classically one says that inheritance describes a ***"is-a"*** relationship, where by going up the inheritance chain we reach higher levels of abstraction.

The first question should always be whether a ***"can-act-as"*** relationship isn't sufficient. In this case, describing the relationship via **interfaces** is often a better choice. Secondly, when adding abstractions, the question must be whether a non-negligible amount of code can work with those abstractions in order to satisfy the features you are seeking.

If there is hardly any code using those abstractions, then they are most likely worthless by themselves. Again, the cost of abstraction is usually lower with interfaces than with base classes.

So, in summary

- A "can-act-as" relationship is usually enough - You then don't need to go for a "is-a" relationship
- The inheritance slot is precious - It can be used only once.
- There are many more ways for code reuse than inheriting from a class
- Base classes and interfaces are abstractions: Make sure that your code can indeed make use of them. If your interface is implemented by only one class, your abstraction is possibly worthless and easily introduced when it becomes necessary.
- If there is a need for abstraction, the penalty is lower on interfaces than on base classes.

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly I've been digging through inheritance hell lately. we quite literally have code that looks like this

```vb
 Public Class A
   ' Do Stuff, methods, members, etc.
     Public var As Object

     Public Sub New()
         member = New Object
     End Sub
 End Class

 ' yes it's empty
 Public Class B : Inherits A
 End Class

 ' yes it's empty
 Public Class C : Inherits A
     Public Sub New()
         MyBase.New()
         member.SomeMethod()
     End Sub
 End Class
```

Then there's the Base class that contains a list of objects that MUST be inherited in order to add objects to that list.

In short, yes inheritance can most certainly be abused, just like everything. Most help for me was to find a good UML modeling tool that will reverse engineer the language you're using.

Comment: The question is tagged C#, that's why C# syntax highlighting is applied.

Comment: No problem! You can specify a language by adding a HTML comment before your code block, like `<!-- language: VB -->`.